# Toggle enabled/disabled electric-pair-local-mode on LaTeX-math-mode-hook

Tags: auctex, electric-pair-mode

I expected the following code would toggle `electric-pair-local-mode` every time I toggle `LaTeX-math-mode` (`CTRL+C ~` in `LaTeX-mode`). It only works one way meaning it does turn on the electric pair mode locally after I have entered the math mode but then Emacs stays in this mode even though I disable the math mode.

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode-hook 'electric-pair-local-mode)
```

I tried things like `(setq electric-pair-local-mode -1)` but evaluating this expression does not make any expected effect meaning Emacs still uses electric pair mode.

I tried to search for similar solutions and it seems checking mode and setting `+1` or `-1` or `t` and `nil` works for other modes but this one. I might be missing something regarding the electric mode and I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C-h f electric-pair-local-mode RET` says:

```
[...]

This is a minor mode.  If called interactively, toggle the
‘Electric-Pair-Local mode’ mode.  If the prefix argument is
positive, enable the mode, and if it is zero or negative, disable
the mode.

If called from Lisp, toggle the mode if ARG is ‘toggle’.  Enable
the mode if ARG is nil, omitted, or is a positive number.
Disable the mode if ARG is a negative number.

[...]
```

You’re calling it from Lisp, so the second paragraph applies.  You can therefore do something along the lines of:

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode-hook (lambda () (electric-pair-local-mode 'toggle))
```

Comment: It's working thanks. I knew about the help but still need to make a habit of checking it first. Thanks